# GraphQL.js circular dependency - "Field type must be Output Type but got: undefined."

Tags: node.js, lambda, graphql, graphql-js

I have been banging my head against this problem for hours. I have a very simple GraphQL implementation in Node.js as follows.

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    username: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
  })
});

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'QueryType',
  fields: () => {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: { id: { name: 'id', type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) } },
      resolve: (parent, args) => getUser(args.id)
    }
  })
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: QueryType,
});
```

It works if the "type" of the "user" field of `QueryType` is anything else (for example, `GraphQLString`). If it's `UserType`, however, I get the following error.

`"Error: User.id field type must be Output Type but got: undefined."`

The stack trace doesn't point anywhere useful, just leads into the GraphQL module itself. This shouldn't be a circular dependency problem as far as I can tell, though I tried thunking it just in case. Any help would be greatly appreciated, because this is driving me nuts.

Comment: You field definition cannot simply be the type, it needs a property `type` with the type. Change `fields: () => ({ id: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString), ... })` to `fields: () => ({ id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }, ... })`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious. Thank you.